# matplotlib y-axis labels wrong

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot some data in matplotlib and I have a twin axis setup but the y-axis labels are  completely wrong for all three of the axes I'm trying to label. I don't want to define a custom range as I will be testing on many datasets and I don't want to go through each time and change the axis labels, I'm not sure what to do.

```py
some data formatting above...

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1)

ax[0].plot(axle_2.temperature, marker = 'x', label = 'temperature')

ax2 = ax[0].twinx()
ax2.plot(axle_2.pressure, color = 'r', marker = 'x', label = 'pressure')
ax2.set_ylabel('pressure (psi)')
ax2.legend()

# cast relevant columns to float
axle_2.pressure = pd.to_numeric(axle_2.pressure)
axle_2.temperature = pd.to_numeric(axle_2.temperature)

axle_2['cold_temp'] = df.apply(lambda x : cold_pressure(x.pressure, x.temperature), axis = 1)

ax[1].plot(axle_2.cold_temp, marker = 'x')

ax[0].grid()
ax[1].grid()

ax[0].set_ylabel(r'temp ($^\circ$C)')

ax[1].set_xlabel('time')
ax[1].set_ylabel(r'temp_cold ($^\circ$C)')

plt.show()
```

The resulting graph looks like:

[image: image of graph result]

Comment: Why do you say the y labels are wrong? Can you share the data you're using, or what printing the data points gives you, so we can see what the correct graph would look like?

Comment: The pressure on the top right goes 56-68-57-69